# How to create an additional network attachment with macvlan CNI plugin in 4.2?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, openshift

I was following the instructions in this link https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/networking/multiple-networks/configuring-macvlan.html

Here it says to edit the networks.operator.openshift.io CustomResource and add the additional network to it.

```
$ oc edit networks.operator.openshift.io cluster

apiVersion: operator.openshift.io/v1
kind: Network
metadata:
  name: cluster
spec:
  additionalNetworks:
  ...
```

I have done that and saved the CustomResource, but when I do  `oc get network-attachment-definitions`, I get `No resources found`.

I have waited about 20 minutes after creating the CustomResource, but no CNO has been created.

Further down the page there is information for [configuring macvlan cni plug-in](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/networking/multiple_networks/configuring-macvlan.html#nw-multus-macvlan-object_configuring-macvlan). I am wondering if the configuration for the plug-in is a prerequisite and where do I configure the plug-in?

Comment: Are you running the ```oc get network-attachment-definitions``` in the same namespace that is supplied in the ```network.operator.openshift.io.cluster.spec.additionalNetworks.namespace``` field?

Comment: if I run **oc get network-attachment-definitions**, i think i'm requesting all resourses from all namespaces , but even with that i get **No resources found**

Comment: There is likely an error message in one of the operators associated with the OpenShift networking. Try checking the pod logs for the related operator pods.

Comment: The pod is not even created .. just keeps creating , so when **oc logs mypod** => **Error, no pod found**